# Button to expand and collapse all on jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have got a simple jQuery accordion, which requires a button at the top for 'expand/collapse all'.

I've got it working so far, except for when some items are already showing, and the button is clicked, the 'other' items expand/collapse - leaving the already open ones to do the opposite.

I need to find some sort of reset that will essentially close and re-open all items, and vice-versa.

See code below for accordion and collapse:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(".faq-accordion > div").accordion({ header: "h4", collapsible: true, active: false, speed: 10000, });
    })
})(jQuery);
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.show-all-applying').click(function() {
    $('.faq-accordion div div').slideToggle("fast");
});
});
</script>
```

Thank you!

Edit: [Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1e6z2ubp/) showing everything as it is so far (with content changed)

The issues are that I need to:

1. Make the 'show all' button also hide everything once it is clicked for a second time.
2. The questions when clicked to close sometimes need to be clicked twice, and not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `slideToggle()`, use `slideUp()` instead ;)

SlideToggel will slide eveything that is up down and everything that is down up.

You want everything to slide up so use slideUp()

**EDIT**: I modified your jsfiddle, and got it working. When a user clicks the button 'show all' it will check what the text is. So in this case 'show all' and it will all slideDown. It then changes the text to 'hide all'. If the user clicks on 'hide all', it will all slideUp. If you use slideToggle in this case, it will work also **BUT** if a user clicks on a question title, and it opens and then clicks on the show all it will **CLOSE** the question title that was clicked on and open all the others!

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1e6z2ubp/3/)**

Comment: That works well thanks. Is there any way to have the button slide everything down on second click, and so on? I want to avoid having 2 seperate buttons for 'up' and 'down' if possible.

Comment: I have edited the question with a JSFiddle link and also clarified the issues

Comment: Another thing... is it possible to speed up the animation of each question opening/closing to the same speed as the 'open/close all'?